# I want regular expression to get only numbers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want a regular expression to get only numbers from a string.I want to ignore the number preceding with a character.
Example : "(a/(b1/8))*100
Here I dont want to fetch b1.I want to get only the numbers like 8,100 etc

Comment: Why are you tagging this with both javascript and asp.net?  Do you need a solution that works in both of these or at least one of these?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), though that would not match after underscores:

```
\b\d+
```

Comment: @Ray - Thanks, quite elegant. I probably should have provided an alternative... I just pointed out the caveat. I can't really tell what the OP is doing - maybe ☃imran wants to ignore underscores. Maybe not. It's one of the mysteries of life.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to regex out numeric (integer) literals from expressions, and so wants to avoid digits that would appear in identifiers.  Of course we would use a lexer for this in real life, because the regex will pick these things up in comments.  I don't think it was a bad question though.  It seems to have been downvoted for the poor English which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<![a-zA-Z])\d+` should work

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have negative lookbehind

Comment: Oh sorry... I forgot javascript regexes are pretty poor... But still good for asp.net, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to find both numbers with and without a leading character, and only keep the ones without:

```
var str = "(a/(b1/8))*100";
var nums = [], s;
var re = /([a-z]?)(\d+)/g;
while (s = re.exec(str)) {
  if (!s[1].length) nums.push(s[2]);
}

alert(nums);
```

Output:

```
8, 100
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/23BnQ/

Answer (score 0):

for only number

```
 ^(\d ? \d* : (\-?\d+))\d*(\.?\d+:\d*) $
```

this will accept any numeric value include -1.4 , 1.3 , 100 , -100

i checked it for my custom numeric validation attribute in asp net

Comment: How well does that work for the example in the question? It should extract `8` and `100` from `(a/(b1/8))*100`.